# Performing a special multiplication on two square matrices

Tags: python, performance, matrix, numpy

I have a function called `mult2` that takes in two square NumPy matrices and returns a matrix that is the result of a special multiplication:

```
p=P(1,344)
PI,PIT=[],[]
for i in xrange(344):
    PI.append(p**i)
    PIT.append((p**i).transpose())

def mult2(a,b):
    C=np.sum((a*b)**2,axis=1)
    CE1=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    API,PITB=[],[]
    AB=a*b
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        API.append(np.diag(np.diag(a*PI[i])))
        PITB.append(np.diag(np.diag(PIT[i]*b)))
        CE1+=np.sum(API[i]*PITB[i]*AB,axis=1)
    CE2=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    BPI,PITA=[],[]
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        BPI.append(np.diag(np.diag(b*PI[i])))
        PITA.append(np.diag(np.diag(PIT[i]*a)))
        CE2+=np.sum(a*BPI[i]*PITA[i]*b,axis=1)
    CE3=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        CE3+=np.sum(AB*API[i]*PITB[i],axis=1)
    CE1E2=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        CE1E2+=np.sum(API[i]*PITB[i]*API[i]*PIT[i]*b,axis=1)
    CE2E3=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        CE2E3+=np.sum(a*BPI[i]*PITA[i]*BPI[i]*PIT[i],axis=1)
    CE1E3=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
            for j in xrange(len(a)):
                CE1E3+=np.sum(np.matrix(API[i]*PITB[i]*API[j]*PITB[j]),axis=1)
    CE1E2E3=np.matrix([[0.0] for _ in xrange(len(a))])
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        CE1E2E3+=np.sum(np.matrix((API[i]*PITB[i])**2),axis=1)
    return C-(CE1+CE2+CE3-CE1E2-CE1E3-CE2E3+CE1E2E3)
```

`p` is another matrix of the same dimensions (`n` by `n`) as `a` and `b` specially a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

My trouble is that these matrices are 344 by 344 and I am looking to run this function lots of times.

Storing the matrices that are used later in the function in the lists actually sped up the computation significantly.

I know this is a very intensive computation so it should take a while to run. That being said, can anyone spot any improvements I can make?

Comment: for anyone interested in the math: http://mymathforum.com/linear-algebra/42813-can-i-calculate-sum-using-matrix-multiplication.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can tell, you could combine all of the for loops into only 2 distinct loops:

1. A loop to setup the matrices used for later calculations
2. A loop to do the rest of the calculations

Instead of performing list comprehension to create an array to pass to each numpy matrix, you could simply multiply a base array by the `len(a)` to create said array:

```
base_list = [[0.0]]*len(a)  # Creates [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], ... ]
```

This way you do not temporarily store each element in the `xrange` object without needing to.

Use more descriptive variable names. What is `a`, `b`? Using more descriptive variable names helps improve comprehension and readability.

---

Here is my version of `mult2()`:

```
def mult2(a, b):

    AB = a*b
    API, BPI, PITA, PITB = [],[],[],[]

    # Base list used to seed each np.matrix()
    base_list= [[0.0]]*len(a)

    C = np.sum((a*b)**2, axis=1)
    CE1 = np.matrix(base_list)
    CE2 = np.matrix(base_list)
    CE3 = np.matrix(base_list)
    CE1E2 = np.matrix(base_list)
    CE2E3 = np.matrix(base_list)
    CE1E3 = np.matrix(base_list)
    CE1E2E3 = np.matrix(base_list)

    # Create arrays used in later matrix calculations
    for index in xrange(len(a)):
        API.append(np.diag(np.diag(a*PI[index])))
        PITB.append(np.diag(np.diag(PIT[index]*b)))
        BPI.append(np.diag(np.diag(b*PI[index])))
        PITA.append(np.diag(np.diag(PIT[index]*a)))

    # Do matrix calculations
    for index in xrange(len(a)):
        CE1 += np.sum(API[index]*PITB[index]*AB, axis=1)
        CE2 += np.sum(a*BPI[index]*PITA[index]*b, axis=1)
        CE3 += np.sum(AB*API[index]*PITB[index], axis=1)
        CE1E2 += np.sum(API[index]*PITB[index]*API[index]*PIT[index]*b, axis=1)
        CE2E3 += np.sum(a*BPI[index]*PITA[index]*BPI[index]*PIT[index], axis=1)
        CE1E2E3 += np.sum(np.matrix((API[index]*PITB[index])**2), axis=1)

        for pos in xrange(len(a)):
            CE1E3 += np.sum(
              np.matrix(API[index]*PITB[index]*API[pos]*PITB[pos]), axis=1)

    return C - (CE1 + CE2 + CE3 - CE1E2 - CE1E3 - CE2E3 + CE1E2E3)
```

---

Remember, good code is readable code: group like statements together.

Also, [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the Python standard style convention. It provides a very nice style guide for code and helps code look as Pythonic as possible.

Comment: my only revision is that there's a problem with using base_list to declare all the matrices. I replaced base_list with [[0.0]]*len(a) and it works perfect

Comment: Huh, odd. You're welcome in any case :D